# LoadError: incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got the `LoadError: incompatible library version` error when I ran `bundle exec rake db:remake:dev`.

I've tried `bundle install` and `gem pristine --all` but neither of them worked.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you like to provide more detail of error stacktrace? In my previous case i ran:

- execute `gem pristine --all`
- in my project's directory, execute `rm -rf vendor` (removes the project specific gem folder)
- and run `bundle update`

hopes help.